# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I'm getting an Uncaught Type error from my JavaScript Validation. Here is the javascript file: http://pastebin.com/hH3vvFTS

and here is the associating HTML: http://pastebin.com/mXHxfxiJ

The full error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined validation.js:38
pwMatchVal validation.js:38
validateForm validation.js:5
onsubmit account.html:362
```

any help is appreciated !

Comment: Please post the relevant code snippet here.....also ID's are unique! and the reason `.value` won't work on `document.forms["Form"]` is because you have multiple forms with the same name. give them all unique ID's and use `document.getElementById("");`. ID = unique. Name = can be used multiple times but the correct dom Method to access them will return a node list (array like object containing dom elements).

Comment: You have multiple forms with same name. It is undefined what happens when same name attribute is used, but what browsers seem to do is to return an array. In your example, document.foo would be a 3-element array, with document.foo[0] being the first form. Here foo is the name of form.

Comment: @MarkWalters Thanks Mark, I changed the form name to Form1 and it works! (I tried this yesterday though :/) thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you have several forms with the same name, so when you access it like this: `document.forms`, `['Form']` will return you to the first page in.